Uniqueness of vector bundle from a collection of transition maps
I started studying vector bundle recently, there is an exercise of constructing a vector bundle from the collection of transition functions. The details are as follows:
Let $K$ be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$. Given an open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of a topological space $X$, for each pair $U_i, U_i \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $U_i \cap U_j \neq \emptyset$, there exists a transition function
$$
    g_{ji}: U_i \cap U_j \to GL(K^r)
$$
Then, there exists a vector bundle $\pi: E \to X$ having transition functions $g_{ji}$. Furthermore, if $X$ is a smooth manifold and $g_{ji}$ are smooth functions, then $\pi: E \to X$ is a smooth vector bundle.
I wonder if the vector bundle is unique (possibly up to homeomorphism).
